# SP 2013 - What's the point of folders in regular lists?

Tags: workflow

I've run into an eventually-to-be issue here. I have a list of items (NOT documents) that needs to have their permission changed from the main list once the item is marked complete.

In order to prevent too many items with unique permissions my main idea was to move the files to a folder and let the items inherit the folders permission.

But I cannot for the life of me find out how to move an item (NOT a document) into a folder using a workflow. I have tried setting the "Folder" value, but that doesn't seem to Work.

Any clues as to what I might have overlooked?

Comment: How did you get a Folder in a List?

Comment: @danny :You have to make changes in order to create the folder in the List

Comment: I can not do this in UI? It needs scripting?

Comment: Simply enter the list settings, under advanced you can set allow folders to yes :-)

Comment: Added 2013 in the header. The old 2010 solution to set the value of the "Folder" field does not Work in 2013!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no standard workflow activity moving items. So we are going to use the "Create List Item" activity. You might think "Copy List Item should also work.". Well, actually, it does not work for this purpose since you cannot change any fields of the item to be moved.

So here is how you move items:

1. Add the "Create List Item" activity.
2. Of the new item, set all field values to the ones of the current
   item.
3. Additionally, set the field "Folder" to the name of the folder where
   the new item should be placed in. (This is where "Copy List Item"
   would fail.)
4. Afterwards delete the current item, so only the new one stays
   present.

Please note: The folder for the new item must already exist.
Of course you can also create completely new items inside a folder. :-)

Read more about this: [How-To: Move items into a folder using a SPD workflow](http://mylittlesharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/05/move-items-into-folder.html)

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention that I have tried that approach (Even though it's horrible for my use case) - and that doesn't work either :-(

I'm confined to using 2013 workflows...